# Proving that $n$ doesn't divide $2^n - 1$ for any integer $n > 1$

Tags: divisibility

> Prove that $n$ doesn't divide $2^n - 1$ for any integer $n$ bigger than $1$.

Thanks in advance! Any questions, please comment!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $n$ is obviously odd. Now let $p$ be the least prime divisor of $n$. Then $2^{n}=1 \mod p$ and $2^{p-1}= 1 \mod p$. But $p-1$ and $n$ are coprime.

Comment: So, primitive roots?

Comment: no, you don't need them, but they make things easier :)
to go without primitive roots consider the smallest $k$ such that $2^k-1$ is divisible by $p$

Comment: So $2^{p-1}$ cannot be congruent to $2^n$ modulo a prime because they are coprime?